# How to install driver Archer T3U Plus for Linux 20.04 (AC1300)

Tags: kali-linux

I get this error when I try to install brand wi-fi, linux:

TP-Link Archer-T3U-Plus AC1300 High Gain Wireless Dual Band USB Adapter

```
kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module: cleaning build area... 'make' KVER=5.15.0-kali3-amd64 src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1.....(bad exit status: 2) Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

Comment: Well, did you "consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/build/make.log for more information"?

Answer (score 3):

You can install the driver from [RinCat](https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver) git repository with support kernel 2.6.24 ~ 5.17:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver.git
cd RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver
make 
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

or use the [Manual DKMS installation](https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver#manual-dkms-installation):